# Странный strlen php

Tags: php

удивительное творится у меня сегодня!
Хотел убрать из строки последний символ

```
$t = 'Приветж';
$t = substr($t,strlen($t)-1);
```

А он мне бах не так показывает длину строки, не те цифры!
что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это из-за кодировки. Используйте функцию [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/mb_strlen).

Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/vsOT66)

Comment: У меня на странице стоит UTF-8 (без BOM)... Вы хотите сказать, что из-за этого?

Comment: @tagir да, на каждый символ уходит по два байта

Answer (score 0):

А делать вот что -- тщательно прочитать и осознать [этот манускрипт](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=mbstring).

Comment: в файле php.ini надо же подключать, правильно?

Comment: нет, в пхп5 он из коробки уже. а лучшее "спасибо" - это кнопка "принять ответ" :)

Comment: я в программировании новичок, и поэтому не понимаю "жаргон" программирования!:(( "из коробки" - это значит, что на странице можно использовать mb_strlen() и он будет работать правильно?

Comment: у меня кодировка на странице utf-8 (без BOM), как я уже писал ранее, думал, что у этой кодировки нет подобных проблем!

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как разобрался!)))

Comment: @tagir - > а лучшее "спасибо" - это кнопка "принять ответ" :)

Answer (score -2):

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // возвращает "abcde"
```